# Invalid arguments passed in implode()

Tags: php, sql, csv

So I have a CSV file that I'm trying to make into a table.

I gave up on the import GUI after too many errors, and am trying to accomplish the import through a php file.

```
//create table with KNOWN values
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE uri_faculty
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        id INT(15),
        lname VARCHAR(50),
        fname VARCHAR(50),
        mi VARCHAR(3),
        Spc_Title VARCHAR(50),
        title VARCHAR(50),
        deptid INT(5),
        dept VARCHAR(50),
        degree1 VARCHAR(10),
        earned1 INT(4),
        school1 VARCHAR(75),
        degree2 VARCHAR(10),
        earned2 INT(4),
        school2 VARCHAR(75),
        degree3 VARCHAR(10),
        earned3 INT(4),
        school3 VARCHAR(75),
        degree4 VARCHAR(10),
        earned4 INT(4),
        school4 VARCHAR(75),
        degree5 VARCHAR(10),
        earned5 INT(4),
        school5 VARCHAR(75),
        degree6 VARCHAR(10),
        earned6 INT(4),
        school6 VARCHAR(75)
        )");

//Get CSV file
$getfile = 'faculty_delim2.csv';
$csvfopen = fopen($getfile, "r");

//loop to fill csvget with arrays
for($i=0;!feof($csvfopen);$i++){
    $array = fgetcsv($csvfopen);
    $insert = implode("','", $array);

    //to exclude the first 2 lines (titles of document)
    if($i>=1){
        //values to be inserted into SQL are displayed
        //echo var_dump($array[$i])." <br> ";

        $sqlval = $insert;
        // var_dump($sqlval);

        //the while loop will constantly place values into the database until the file is finished
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO uri_faculty (id,lname,fname,mi,Spc_Title,title,deptid,dept,
                    degree1,earned1,school1,
                    degree2,earned2,school2,
                    degree3,earned3,school3,
                    degree4,earned4,school4,
                    degree5,earned5,school5,
                    degree6,earned6,school6,) VALUES ('$sqlval')
        ");
    }
}
fclose($csvfopen);
echo "complete";

?>
```

I keep getting an error saying that implode is receiving incorrect parameters, yet every bit of documentation I've found says that I am correct.

I changed the permissions of the file, and it is in the right place.

Comment: Quite what is `for($i=0;!feof($csvfopen);$i++){` supposed to be doing? Why not use a simple `while(!feof($csvfopen)){`

Comment: You're trying to do a one-off import?  Why not familiarize yourself with [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)? That is really the best way to do this, since in PHP you need to account for all the quoting, escaping, etc.

Comment: @user3678068, `','` is the delimeter that he is imploding the array on, in order to build the string for the query.

Comment: @Brobin. oops, i mixed implode and explode...

Comment: `var_dump($array)`. you're probably getting a boolean false, which means fgetcsv failed.

Comment: In your CREATE TABLE, you have 2 fields called id, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
for($i=0;!feof($csvfopen);$i++){
    $array = fgetcsv($csvfopen);
```

I would write this:

```
while ($array = fgetcsv($csvfopen)) {
```

The loop will automatically finish when there are no more rows to read. Your error is probably an edge case, where the file still thinks it is not at `feof` but in spite of that, there are no more rows, and `fgetcsv` returns **false**.

By the way, two other issues:

1. You will run into another error soon:

   ```
   . . . degree6,earned6,school6,) VALUES . . .
   ```

   You must not put a comma after the last column. Write this instead:

   . . . degree6,earned6,school6) VALUES . .
2. You are wide open to SQL injection issues. What happens when one of your CSV fields contains an apostrophe? You should learn how to use PDO with query parameters. Or failing that, use escaping:

   ```
   $insert = implode("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array));
   ```

Finally, you should consider skipping fgetcsv and use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Then all your CSV issues, and escaping issues just go away.

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'faculty_delim2.csv' INTO TABLE uri_faculty IGNORE 2 LINES");
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried commenting out everything except the CREATE and the LOAD DATA LINE. I checked the table and the id column was filled, but everything else was NULL.